# MySQL Stored Procedure : delete entry if table exists

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, psql

I have created a stored procedure, which should delte data from some tables.

On my productive db I have tables which I have not in my local db (different schema names).

Is there an elegant way to query the data tables existence to avoid exceptions? Maybe declare an error handler which catches the specific error and should continue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deletion`(IN s_id varchar(255))
BEGIN   
    DECLARE has_error BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    /* for all other exception there should be a rollback, if table does not exist
        then continue*/
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET has_error = TRUE; 

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM a WHERE id = s_id;
DELETE FROM b WHERE id = s_id;
DELETE FROM c WHERE id = s_id;
DELETE FROM d WHERE id = s_id;

IF has_error THEN
  ROLLBACK;
 ELSE
  COMMIT;
END IF;

END
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this, but this is not working. even if the table exists the entry is not deleted:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'a' ) then
        DELETE FROM at WHERE id = s_id; 
    END IF;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a table per date/customer design?

Comment: Check that they exist in information_schema.tables.

Comment: The schema names are different.

Comment: Why is that an impediment?

Comment: Isn´t it? I thought 
you have to specify the exact name in the stored procedure. Can you show me an example please.